# silverstripe init() function

Tags: php, silverstripe

Can someone explain this code in **Silverstripe**:

```
public function init() {
    RSSFeed::linkToFeed($this->Link() . "rss");   
    parent::init();
}
```

What exactly is init function?

what `parent::init();`

exactly do in code

Comment: It calls the static `init()` function from the parent class, if this answers your question?!

Comment: does init() belongs to silverstripe or php knowledge base?

Comment: It's a function from `silverstripe`, question answered?

Comment: yes i woul like to know where to read what this function exactly do. but i dont know where to look. is there any tutorial for it

Comment: The function which you extends from this class there is the function definition

Comment: Here is the api documentation for the `Controller` class, which contains the `init()` function: 
http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Controller.html

Comment: And here is the source documentation for the `init()` function: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Controller.html#66-86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php classes when you overwrite a method of parent class you still can call the parent class with this code, it will help you to put some code at the beginning of the real method without removing it.

you can find out more about it at [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php)

Comment: does it mean that that init() is method of parent class and i overide it with declaring my function / public function init() / but i was inside that function called method parent::init() from higher order class?

Comment: yes, so the main init() method will work, but you do something before that

Answer (score 1):

The upmost init() method is defined in the Controller class.
Then ContentController extends Controller, which overrides the Controller class's init() method, but it's also calling parent::init() on the first line. Then usually you define all your page controller classes like this (for any new page type), in the example below for the default Page_Controller class:

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

  public function init() {
    parent::init();

    // do your own stuff here
  }

}
```

So this is the traditional PHP based class extension mechanism, but Silverstripe also allows you to use Extensions and Data Extensions, which is basically extending the functionality of already existing controllers, data objects. I won't go into details with this... You can find out more about this here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/extending/extensions/

I usually have something like this in my controller classes:

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

  public function init() {
    parent::init();

    // do your own stuff here

    $this->extend('updateInit');
  }

}
```

Notice the `$this->extend('updateInit');` line above.

I can have another extension defined for the Page_Controller class inside a YAML config file somewhere, and than have the updateInit() method defined in that class. Example:

```
class Page_Controller_Extension extends Extension {

  public function updateInit() {

    // do some more stuff here

  }

}
```

...and in this case you would have something like this in a YAML config file:

```
---
Name: siteextensions
After:
  - 'framework/*'
  - 'cms/*'
---

Page_Controller:
  extensions:
    - Page_Controller_Extension
```

Note that this is not really the traditional way of extending classes, like in PHP, it's more like defining some decorators for a controller class. Also, to refer to the parent, or object being decorated, you can't use just `$this`, you'll need to use `$this->owner`. Example below:

```
class Page_Controller_Extension extends Extension {

  public function updateInit() {
    // do some more stuff here

    if ($this->owner->IsFeatured) {
      // do something here
    }
  }

}
```

You usually decorate controllers extending the `Extension` class, and you extend the `DataExtension` class if you want to decorate DataObjects - works the same way as explained above.

Comment: I do really recommend using an IDE like for example PHPStorm to move arround the Silverstripe core code. You can just CTRL+click on the init() method in the parent::init() line and it will jump to the ContentController class's init() method in the IDE... there again you can CTRL+click on the init() method in the parent::init() line, and it will jump to the Controller class's init() method. It's  avery quick way of jumping between different classes, methods and so on... It also helps a lot understanding the class hierarchy in Silverstripe, or for that matter in any PHP project.